# Space complexity of isSubtree function for 2 binary trees

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, complexity-theory

```
public boolean isSubtree(TreeNode root, TreeNode subRoot) {
        if (root == null) return false;
        return areSame(root, subRoot) || isSubtree(root.left, subRoot) || isSubtree(root.right, subRoot);
    }

    public boolean areSame(TreeNode root, TreeNode subRoot) {
        if (root == null && subRoot == null) return true;
        if (root == null || subRoot == null) return false;
        if (subRoot.val != root.val)
            return false;
        return areSame(root.left, subRoot.left) && areSame(root.right, subRoot.right);
    }
```

Is the space compelxity of my above solution to find if a tree [is subtree](https://leetcode.com/problems/subtree-of-another-tree/) of another binary tree - O(height(tree1)) (as suggested in most of the discussion comments) or O(height(tree1)+ height(tree2)) where

I think it should be O(height(tree1) + height(tree2)) because `isSubtree` can go as deep as one branch of tree1, and for each call, the isSame() could go as deep as height(tree2), so the maximum stack memory being used at any instant would be ht1+ht2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the boolean operators `&&` and `||` are short-circuiting operators (as they are in Java), the recursion depth (and extra stack memory) is upper bounded by `O(height(tree1))`.

Since `isSubtree(root, subRoot)` can only call itself (with the first tree's height reduced by 1) or `areSame(root, subRoot)`, and *at most one call of 'areSame' directly from 'isSubtree'* can be on the stack at a time (because of short-circuiting), the recursion depth is `O(height(tree1)) + max-depth-of(areSame(tree1, tree2))`.

Now, `areSame(root, subRoot)` makes no recursive calls if `root` is null. If `root` is not null, it may call:

```
areSame(root.left, subRoot.left) && areSame(root.right, subRoot.right);
```

Here, it calls `areSame` only with child nodes of root: the height of the first tree has been reduced by `1`, and the first call must complete before the second call starts (since `&&` short-circuits). So there can be at most `height(tree1) + 1` calls to `areSame` on the call-stack at any time, so the total recursion depth/ stack space of `isSubtree` is `O(height(tree1))`